# Keep all cells above given value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to discard all cells that contain a value below a given value. So not only the rows or only the columns that, but for for all cells.

Tried code below, where all values in each cell should be at least 3. Doesn't work.

```
df[(df >= 3).any(axis=1)]
```

Example

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'A':[1,5,6,2],'B':[9,9,1,2],'C':[1,1,3,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df
    A   B   C
0   1   9   1
1   5   9   1
2   6   1   3
3   2   2   5
```

I want to keep only the cells that are at least 3.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean "only cells that are least 3".  A dataframe is a rectangular structure.

Comment: "all values in each cell should be at least 3". So all values in a given row should be >= 3.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ that isn't true.  "So not only the rows or only the columns that, but for for all cells." is inconsistent with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "all values in each cell should be at least 3"

```
df [df < 3] = 3
df

    A   B   C
0   3   9   3
1   5   9   3
2   6   3   3
3   3   3   5
```

If you want "to keep only the cells that are at least 3"

```
df = df [df >= 3]
df

    A   B   C
0   NaN 9.0 NaN
1   5.0 9.0 NaN
2   6.0 NaN 3.0
3   3.0 3.0 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value is >= 3 then drop all rows with NaN value.

```
df[df >= 3 ].dropna()
```

DEMO:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'A':[1,5,6,3],'B':[9,9,1,3],'C':[1,1,3,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df

    A   B   C
0   1   9   1
1   5   9   1
2   6   1   3
3   3   3   5

df = df[df >= 3 ].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
df

    A   B   C
0   3.0 3.0 5.0
```

Comment: That's an empty dataframe.

Comment: This would return an empty dataframe in this use case not sure that is what the OP is going for

Comment: That is all rows in which each value is greater than or equal to three. OP asked to only keep cells that are greater than or equal to three.  That implies they want to keep Row 1, Column A with a value of 5 while dropping Row 1, Column C with a value of 1.  This makes no sense in a dataframe context.

Comment: let us wait for his expected output. It will be funny to have a panda dataframe with holes in it. :)